# Assign only the days of the current week in datepicker Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
   child: DateTimeField(
   controller: _fechaController,
   validator: (value) {
   if (value == "") {
   return 'Requerido*';
   }
   return null;
   },
                          format: format,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Fecha"),
                          onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
                            return showDatePicker(
                                context: context,
                                firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                                lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

I only need to assign the current days of the week and well in the future depending on radio buttons that show me the days of the month, is this possible?

I tried using the methods provided by ***datetime_picker_formfield: ^ 1.0.0*** but I can't get the solution